# PHP Iterate and Display XML data

Tags: php, xml

I need to read XML data and display them on my HTML page.
I'm using php scripts to ready, parse and display the data.

Here an example of my XML file:

```
<info>
    <data>
        <aaa>AAAA</aaa>
        <bbb>BBBB</bbb>
        <ccc>CCC</ccc>
        <aaa>RRRR</aaa>    (*)
        <bbb>PPPP</bbb>    (*)     
        <ccc>ZZZZ</ccc>    (*)
    </data>
     <data>
        <aaa>YYYY</aaa>
        <bbb>TTTT</bbb>
        <ccc>WWWW</ccc>
        <aaa>QQQQ</aaa>    (*)
        <bbb>PPPP</bbb>    (*)     
        <ccc>ZZZZ</ccc>    (*)
         ...
</info>
```

I'm able to read the first values of the tags "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" (for each "data" tag), but not the others (N.B: the tags are the same, the value instead change). I don't know how to access to this values (see marker (*) )

Here the piece of code that tries to iterate the XML structure:

```
 $myConf = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
 for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($myConf->data); $i++) {
     echo '<td>'.$myConf->data[$i]->aaa.'<BR>'.$myConf->data[$i]->bbb.'</td>'
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must loop through `$data["aaa"]` that it's a array of values for the `<aaa>`, see a example:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<info>
  <data>
    <aaa>AAAA</aaa>
    <bbb>BBBB</bbb>
    <ccc>CCC</ccc>
    <aaa>RRRR</aaa>
    <bbb>PPPP</bbb>
    <ccc>ZZZZ</ccc>
  </data>
  <data>
    <aaa>YYYY</aaa>
    <bbb>TTTT</bbb>
    <ccc>WWWW</ccc>
    <aaa>QQQQ</aaa>
    <bbb>PPPP</bbb>
    <ccc>ZZZZ</ccc>
  </data>
</info>
XML;

$xe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($xe->data as $data) {
  foreach ($data as $tag => $value) {
    printf("tag: %s => %s\n", $tag, $value);
  }
}
```

output:

```
tag: aaa => AAAA
tag: bbb => BBBB
tag: ccc => CCC
tag: aaa => RRRR
tag: bbb => PPPP
tag: ccc => ZZZZ
tag: aaa => YYYY
tag: bbb => TTTT
tag: ccc => WWWW
tag: aaa => QQQQ
tag: bbb => PPPP
tag: ccc => ZZZZ
```

Comment: I should use php for this task using the previous code

Comment: @user3472065 I don't understand what you mean with "I should use php for this task", what I wrote isn't php ?